# Is there any performance/memory difference in making copies of a list these ways?

Tags: flutter, dart

The answers to this question:

[Multiple lists share same reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72799895/multiple-lists-share-same-reference)

Made me wonder. Is there any difference in making a copy of a list by doing

```
list.toList()
```

or

```
[...list]
```

Does it do exactly the same "under the hood" or is one more efficient than the other? I would think that `toList()` would be the better one since the other method needs to unpack and pack the list again, but maybe the same happens in the first method.

Comment: You can look https://stackoverflow.com/a/55843172/13109852

Comment: @SalihCan The linked answer is for JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an official answer and I hope one with better knowledge can correct me if I am wrong.

In short, both should result in the same performance and behavior.

We can observe this using `--disassemble` with the Dart VM 2.17.5, where it looks like `[...list]` is being translated into `List.of(list1)`. The `List.of` is defined here:

```dart
  @patch
  factory List.of(Iterable<E> elements, {bool growable: true}) {
    if (growable) {
      return _GrowableList.of(elements);
    } else {
      return _List.of(elements);
    }
  }
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/9ad08f1c951ae8b5ee0387306f450afaccf4eaba/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/array_patch.dart#L48-L55

Since we can only create growable lists with the `[]` syntax, then we follow the track into `_GrowableList.of` which is defined as:

```dart
  factory _GrowableList.of(Iterable<T> elements) {
    if (elements is _GrowableList) {
      return _GrowableList._ofGrowableList(unsafeCast(elements));
    }
    if (elements is _Array) {
      return _GrowableList._ofArray(unsafeCast(elements));
    }
    if (elements is EfficientLengthIterable) {
      return _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable(unsafeCast(elements));
    }
    return _GrowableList._ofOther(elements);
  }
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/eb17dad60440daeb5998751db8311d82769cfb64/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/growable_array.dart#L142-L153

So as we can see, Dart will try and check if the provided `Iterable` is actually some other specific type. The common thing here is that we prefer to know the final size of the created new `List` but `Iterable` cannot safely, by default, be checked for its length without iterating over all elements in the `Iterable`. So if we know the `Iterable` is actually a type where we safely can get the `length`, without any iteration, we should use that size.

The `toList()` method is implemented differently for different types of object in Dart and is therefore a way to have an efficient way to make a list from that object. E.g. if we have an `_GrowableList`, the `toList()` for that can be found here:

```dart
  List<T> toList({bool growable: true}) {
    // ...
    final length = this.length;
    if (growable) {
      if (length > 0) {
        final data = new _List(_adjustedCapacity(length));
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          data[i] = this[i];
        }
        final result = new _GrowableList<T>._withData(data);
        result._setLength(length);
        return result;
      }
      return <T>[];
    } else {
      if (length > 0) {
        final list = new _List<T>(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          list[i] = this[i];
        }
        return list;
      }
      return List<T>.empty(growable: false);
    }
  }
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/eb17dad60440daeb5998751db8311d82769cfb64/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/growable_array.dart#L509-L540

And we can see in this implementation that since it is already a `_GrowableList`, it knows it can get the `length` efficiently and then uses that in its implementation for creating a new list based.